# Temporary profile instead of my regular one

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, windows-domain

I have windows-7 OS laptop connected to Domain, after installation it worked for a few weeks. Now, after logging it shows users logged in with temporary profile. My original *desktop* and *My Documents* files are gone.

Comment: have you logged in with your domain's account or your system's account.

Answer (score 0):

For this, once when your computer boots up, login to a temporary profile and navigate to `C:\users\%yourlogin%` and make a backup of your data.

This is most likely because your user profile is corrupted.

Navigate to `HKLM/software/microsoft/windowsnt/profilelist` and search for your profile and delete the same.

Now try to login to your computer using your login and restore the data.